# how to call spring jap query none parameters

Tags: jpa, named-query, hibernate-native-query

I use spring data jpa with native query

I have already some query like this

How to use native query none parameter.

```
String q="SELECT t1.blockNumber-1 FROM someTAble t1 LEFT JOIN  someTAble t2 ON t2.blockNumber = t1.blockNumber-1 WHERE t2.blockNumber IS NULL AND t1.blockNumber> 0 ORDER BY t1.blockNumber";

@Query(value = q,nativeQuery = true)
List<Entity> findByBlockNumberIs();
```

they are occur errors Column 'sequence' not found.

That query means are when i insert some Contiguous data int value then i find missing data.

But 
 this query working

```
SELECT *,t1.blockNumber-1 FROM someTAble t1 LEFT JOIN  someTAble t2 ON t2.blockNumber = t1.blockNumber-1 WHERE t2.blockNumber IS NULL AND t1.blockNumber> 0 ORDER BY t1.blockNumber
```

The difference between the two queries is whether there is a '*' or not

how to change simple to my query.

How to i changed error

OR How to use spring data jpa predicate

```
  QEntity qBe1=  QEntity .blockEntity;
         QEntity qBe2=  QEntity .blockEntity;


        build.and(qBe2.blockNumber.eq(be.getBlockNumber()-1))

                .and(qBe2.blockNumber.isNull().and(qBe1.blockNumber.gt(0)));
```

is predicate can use left join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well...

use this.

```
List<Integer> findByBlockNumber()
```